# How to tell Hadoop to connect to the loopback interface in pseudodistributed mode

Tags: hadoop

I have a pseudodistributed hadoop configuration and I am in a network with DHCP with IPs that expires every 6 hours. When I start a long running process the IP changes and the job fails with the message:

```
Retrying connect to server: <ip>/<ip>:55506. Alredy tried <X> time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries = 3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECOND)
```

It retries the three times and it fails afterwars. The IP is a private IP 10.x.x.x.

My question is if there is a way I can tell hadoop in a configuration file to connect to the loopback address or any other way I can stop hadoop from failing in this manner? I have looked at some configurations but haven't found anything that might help. If not then I guess I'll have to set up a small network.

Comment: Changing to the loopback will only make the machine talk to itself. I would suggest you talk to the network administrator to give you a static IP, or set it up on your router if that's you. Otherwise, use DNS names instead of IPs. Most importantly, Zookeeper (if you use highly available Hadoop) will not work well with changing IP addresses

Comment: Right I guess the only other solution is to change the mode to standalone. After thinking a while I think that is what the standalone mode is for. Thanks for the comment I think I'll switch to the standalone mode and only use distributed mode when the cluster is finished, thanks.

Comment: If you're using "pseudodistributed" mode, and set up /etc/hosts entry to just your machine's hostname, then it'll work fine (assuming Linux)

Comment: Right pseudodistributed, sorry for the lapse I edited the question thanks. I'll try the hosts file. It is running on windows at the moment, only availiable server for testing.

Comment: If you have the hardware available, Hortonworks and Cloudera offer a VM with Hadoop (and lots of extra, useful features). Otherwise, plenty of Vagrant or Docker-based Hadoop solutions exist on the web